# How to connect boost to office365 with STARTTLS?

Tags: c++, openssl, smtp, office365, boost-asio

I am using `boost::ssl` to connect to `smtp.office365.com:587`. Socket uses `boost::context` to establish an SSL connection, and `tcp::resolver` to resolve the service name and port. After that, trying to connect the socket, the connection is successful, but I can't read or write to the socket afterwards.

```cpp
class SMTPClient
{
    typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssl_socket;

    public:
        SMTPClient(
            const std::string& pServer,
            unsigned int pPort,
            const std::string& pUser,
            const std::string& pPassword )
            : mServer(pServer)
            , mPort(pPort)
            , mUserName(pUser)
            , mPassword(pPassword)
            , mContext(mIOService, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::tlsv1)
            , mSocket(mIOService, mContext)
            , mResolver(mIOService)
        {
            mContext.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_peer);
            mSocket.set_verify_callback(
            boost::bind(&SMTPClient::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

            tcp::resolver::query qry(mServer, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(mPort));
            mResolver.async_resolve( qry, boost::bind( &SMTPClient::handleResolve, this, _1,_2));
        }

        bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
            boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
        {
            char subject_name[256];
            X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
            X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

            LOG("Verifying " << subject_name << " preverified: " << preverified);

            return true;
        } 

        bool send(
            const std::string& from,
            const std::string& to,
            const std::string& subject,
            const std::string& message,
            std::string& error)
        {
            mFrom=from;
            mTo=to;
            mSubject=subject;
            mMessage=message;
            mIOService.run();
            error = mErrorMsg;
            return mHasError;
        }

    private:
        std::string encodeBase64(const std::string& data)
        {
            LOG(data);
            std::stringstream os;
            std::copy(
                base64_text(
                    data.c_str()),
                    base64_text(data.c_str() + data.size()),
                    std::ostream_iterator<char>(os)
                );
            LOG(os.str());
            return os.str();
        }

        std::string dencodeBase64(const std::string& data)
        {
            LOG(data);
            std::stringstream os;
            std::copy(
                base64_dec(
                    data.c_str()),
                    base64_dec(data.c_str() + data.size()),
                    std::ostream_iterator<char>(os)
                );
            LOG(os.str());
            return os.str();
        }

        void handleResolve(const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        {
            if(error.value() == boost::system::errc::success)
            {
                tcp::endpoint endpoint=*endpoint_iterator;
                mSocket.lowest_layer().async_connect(
                    endpoint,
                    boost::bind(
                        &SMTPClient::handleConnect,
                        this,
                        _1,
                        ++endpoint_iterator)
                    );
            }
            else
            {
                mHasError=true;
                mErrorMsg= error.message();
            }
        }

        void writeLine(const std::string& data)
        {
            std::ostream req_strm(&mRequest);
            req_strm << data << "\r\n";
            boost::asio::write(mSocket, mRequest);
            req_strm.clear();
        }

        void log_ssl()
        {
            int err;
            while (err = ERR_get_error()) {
                char *str = ERR_error_string(err, 0);
                if (!str)
                    return;
                LOG(str);
            }
        }

        void handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        {
            if (error.value() == boost::system::errc::success)
            {
                //mSocket.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));

                //
                
                // The connection was successful. Send the request.
                std::ostream req_strm(&mRequest);
                read();
                writeLine("EHLO " + mServer);
                read();
                writeLine("STARTTLS")
                mSocket.handshake(ssl_socket::client);
                writeLine("AUTH PLAIN");
                read();
            }
            else
            {
                mHasError=true;
                mErrorMsg= error.message();
            }
        }

        void read() {
            static int round = 0;
            size_t s = -1;
            while(s > 0 || s == -1)
            {
                LOG(round++);
                const int max_length = 4096;
                char data[max_length];
                boost::system::error_code error;
                s = mSocket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);
                LOG("Size: " << s);
                if (error) {
                    LOG("error: " << error.message());
                    return;
                }
                if(s > 0)
                {
                    char buffer[4096];
                    strncpy(buffer, data, s);
                    buffer[s] = '\0';
                    LOG( "buffer:" << buffer );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        std::string mServer;
        std::string mUserName;
        std::string mPassword;
        std::string mFrom;
        std::string mTo;
        std::string mSubject;
        std::string mMessage;
        unsigned int mPort;
        boost::asio::io_service mIOService;
        tcp::resolver mResolver;
        boost::asio::ssl::context mContext;
        ssl_socket mSocket;
        boost::asio::streambuf mRequest;
        boost::asio::streambuf mResponse;
        bool mHasError;
        std::string mErrorMsg;
};

bool send_mail(std::string text, std::string &error)
{
    std::string 
        subject = "Subject",
        me_mail = "MAIL",
        me_mail_server = "smtp.office365.com", 
        me_user = "USER",
        me_pass = "PASS",
        target_mail = "TARGET";

    int server_port = 587;

    SMTPClient mailc(me_mail_server, server_port, me_user, me_pass);
    return mailc.send(me_mail, target_mail, subject, text, error);
}
```

So, after starting this, I can't read from the socket. If reading is executed then I catch an exception that read in not initialized. And the same for writing.

As I understand, the connection sequence for `STARTTLS` is not going as it should be. If I will switch to another port and protocol type, like SSL, it will work.

So please, help me to repair it, and establish a connection to `smpt.office365.com`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual code you are having trouble with. Office365's port 587 is an *explicit TLS* port (the *implicit SSL/TLS* port is 465 instead). An SMTP client is expected to connect to an explicit TLS port initially unencrypted and then issue an SMTP `STARTTLS` command before performing a TLS handshake.  `openssl.exe` requires the `-starttls smtp` command in order to issue `STARTTLS`, otherwise it will perform the TLS handshake immediately upon connecting, which won't work on port 587 (only on port 465).

Comment: @RemyLebeau office365 doesn't support 465 port and seems that office support STARTTLS handshake.

Comment: "*office365 doesn't support 465 port*" - perhaps, but plenty of other SMTP servers do, so it is good info to be aware of. "*and seems that office support STARTTLS handshake*" - it **requires** a `STARTTLS` handshake on port 587. The command `openssl s_client -connect smtp.office365.com:587 -tls1_2` does not use `STARTTLS`, thus the need for `-starttls smtp`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I changed my code and can connect already to office365:587 and see "HELO" and "STARTTLS". as I understood if the server accepts "STARTTLS" and react successfully like  "...ready for STARTTLS" then I need to create a new connection with using TLS and execute TLS handshake, am I right?

Comment: "*I need to create a new connection*" - no. You have to execute the TLS handshake using the same TCP connection you used to send `STARTTLS`.

Comment: from boost socket, I can take native_handler() and from openssl SSL_do_handshake how can I match them or can you please suggest another way?

Comment: @RemyLebeau from boost socket, I can take native_handler() and from openssl SSL_do_handshake how can I match them or can you please suggest another way?

Comment: first off, you should not be calling `SSL_do_handshake()` directly, use `SSL_connect()` instead. But either way, you need to create an `SSL` object using `SSL_new()` and then assign the socket to it using `SSL_set_fd()`. But, since you are using Boost for the socket, why are you not [using Boost to handle TLS](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html), too?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I used boost::ssl but there only is SSL and TLS connection and if I use TLSv1_2 on phase handshake receiving an error like "wrong version" and I figure out that "office365" support only STARTTLS.

Comment: Boost works just fine with `STARTTLS` when used correctly. If you are having trouble with it, you are likely using it wrong. Which goes back to my very first comment: "***Please [edit] your question to show the actual code you are having trouble with.***" I'm done commenting until you do that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau done, please see.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing the TLS handshake too soon.

Office365's port 587 is an *explicit TLS* port. An SMTP client is expected to connect to that port initially unencrypted and then issue an SMTP `STARTTLS` command before performing a TLS handshake.  But you are not sending a `STARTTLS` command. You are performing the TLS handshake immediately upon connecting. That will not work on port 587.

Once you are connected to the server, use the underlying socket to read the server's *unencrypted* greeting, then send an *unencrypted* `EHLO` command, followed by an *unencrypted* `STARTTLS` command, THEN perform the TLS handshake.

The "wrong version number" error is because `handshake()` is interpreting the server's SMTP greeting as a TLS handshake response, which it is not.

If you search online, there are examples that show how to use Boost to implement an SMTP client with STARTTLS support. For instance:

https://github.com/Plaristote/crails/blob/master/modules/mail/src/smtp.cpp

Comment: now I don't call handshake and after successful connection, I read from the socket and I receive next: what():  *write: uninitialized*

Comment: the above error, is from write, but the read gives same

Comment: Again, you need to SHOW YOUR CODE or nobody can help you.

Comment: sorry, please check I added full code

Comment: @ichik You are getting errors because you are attempting to read/write using the TLS stream before it has established a TLS session. You need to read/write using the underlying TCP socket until the TLS handshake is performed, then read/write using the TLS stream instead.

Comment: @ichik Also, your `read()` function is completely wrong for handling the SMTP protocol. You are just reading arbitrary bytes without any regard to the meaning behind them. SMTP has structure to it, which you are completely ignoring. In particular, you need to read data in CRLF-delimited lines, and there may be more than 1 line per response. I strongly suggest you read [RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321), particularly [Section 4.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.2).

Comment: @ichik Also, you are not reading the server's `STARTTLS` response before initiating the TLS handshake, so the handshake is going to fail when it receives and misinterprets the `STARTTLS` response as a TLS handshake response. You need to pay attention to the SMTP response codes and perform the TLS handshake ONLY if the `STARTTLS` response says it is OK to do so. I strongly suggest you read [RFC 3207](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3207).

Answer (score 0):

The main use that I am using SSL socket for establishing the connection.

How it should be in case of ***STARTTLS*** :

```
typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> SslSocket;

boost::asio::ssl::context ssl_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1);
SslSocket ssl_sock(io_service, ssl_context);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock(ssl_sock.next_layer());
```

Here you have two sockets one is SSL secured and another not.
first of you should to use not secured for connection and start negotiation with *Server*, then execute ***STARTTLS*** and father that switch *ssl_socket* and execute handshake:

```
void Server::connect(const std::string& hostname, unsigned short port)
{
  boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
  tcp::resolver             resolver(io_service);
  tcp::resolver::query      query(hostname, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(port));
  tcp::resolver::iterator   endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
  tcp::resolver::iterator   end;


  while (error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
    sock.close();
    sock.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
  }

  if (error) {
      std::cout<< error.message() << std::endl;
  }
  handshake();
}

void Server::handshake()
{
  // Receiving the server identification
  boost::system::error_code error;
  server_id = read_answer(220);
  server_message << "EHLO " << 
  sock.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << "\r\n";
  write_message();
  read_answer(250);
  server_message << "STARTTLS" << "\r\n";
  write_message();
  read_answer(220);
  ssl_sock.handshake(SslSocket::client, error);
  server_message << "EHLO " << sock.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << "\r\n";
  write_message();
  read_answer(250);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).